# How do I conduct research on healthcare patients' experiences effectively and ethically?

Tags: research, ethics, health

I'm working on a side project to help improve patients' healthcare outcomes. This is an independent project and I am not affiliated with any organization. I want to learn about people's experiences in healthcare. Specifically I want to learn how doctors and healthcare professionals failed to treat patients or meet their needs.

This of course presents many ethical and legal concerns, and as this is an independent project, I want to be especially careful. I also have to conduct this research in a lean way as my time is limited.

So, any suggestions on how to get started? Is there an existing body of research that I could sift through to avoid having to do my own research?

Comment: You could anonymize the data (patients & doctors and other personal details), and from there you could ask more direct questions. Make it clear that personal information will not be recorded and/or collection.

Comment: You're right, you're putting yourself in a tricky situation. I work for a health insurance company and we have strict rules around gathering, storing, and sharing data that might include patient information. (It sounds like you're not affiliated with an IRB, who could provide their requirements, right?)

Comment: Right, @KenMohnkern . Research may be impossible, unfortunately

Comment: You're just looking for patient satisfaction? There must be something published about that somewhere. You might want to add [scholar.google.com](https://scholar.google.com/) to your bookmarks.

Comment: More specific info than that. Why were they dissatisfied, what steps did they take to gain satisfaction, what ultimately resolved the situation (if anything)...

Comment: Medical errors are often 'system errors'.   Ie they are composed of a number of interacting components.  Medics tend to cover up errors rather than share them , a topic which is covered in Mathew Syed's book "Black Box Thinking"

Comment: I'm not sure why you're asking a healthcare research ethics question on a UX Q&A site, or whether you think the answers will be any better than if you asked a UX question on a healthcare research ethics site. I would strongly recommend getting in touch with a researcher or organisation in the field in question for advice. Privacy of health data is a serious matter. There may be laws.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not about user experience

Comment: That's fine, but I disagree. The question concerns conducting UX research and designing an experience to help patients, which is all relevant to UX.

Comment: @nekomatic Again, this is a UX question in the domain of healthcare. Ethics is a common topic in the design of personal informatics applications. It's clear my question is too challenging for this community, which is fine, but I find it strange that people would rather flag it than admit they don't know the answer.

Comment: @user50599 Even if the question is too challenging for this community, I don't think it is a reason to neglect it. However, there might be a few more details that you need to furnish in order for a better answer to be provided, or to get more attention from the community.

Comment: @MichaelLai you're two months too late. This question is no longer relevant to my work.

Answer (score 2):

You could create a release form that people being interviewed have to sign to get written consent of their voluntary participation. There, you can  include terms regarding their privacy, and as they mentioned before specify that information will be anonymized. If you are doing the research to improve a system - being open from the beginning, stating your intentions, and the participants written consent would be a good start.

Answer (score 1):

First and foremost, read all the HIPAA information you can find. There are all sorts of requirements around the training of people who have access to the data, the security of the site where the information will be processed and many other issues that can arise. I've been through the training and my company had to be certified as compliant. The laws are very strict and they are enforced.

As far as research you can sift through, there are several companies that are working in that space and can provide you with accurate information that has been filtered for identifying data. But most will cost you for access as that is their bread and butter.

However, there is something called HCAHPS which is a free database of survey information that might be helpful to your needs located here [link]http://www.hcahpsonline.org/home.aspx

It's not an easy site to sort through but I know the data is there and is available somewhere. lol